# Display the customer phone in WooCommerce new account email notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-data, email-notifications

How can I display Phone number in new account registration email?

I have add Phone number field like:

```
<p class="form-row form-row-wide"> <label for="reg_billing_phone">Phone <span class="required">*</span></label> <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_phone" id="reg_billing_phone" value=""></p>
```

The Customer new Account email template code is *(Where I want to display the number phone)*:

```
<?php
/**
 * Customer new account email
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-new-account.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

    <p><?php printf( __( 'Thanks for creating an account on %1$s. Your username is %2$s', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $blogname ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_login ) . '</strong>' ); ?></p>

<?php if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) && $password_generated ) : ?>

    <p><?php printf( __( 'Your password has been automatically generated: %s', 'woocommerce' ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_pass ) . '</strong>' ); ?></p>
<p>Phone No:<?php echo get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_phone', true ) ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>

    <p><?php printf( __( 'You can access your account area to view your orders and change your password here: %s.', 'woocommerce' ), make_clickable( esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) ) ); ?></p>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need the $user ID and in the template you got the $user_login (user login name) you can use [`get_user_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/) Wordpress function this way:

```
// Get the user object (from the user login)
$user = get_user_by( 'login', $user_login );

// Get the user ID
$user_id = $user->ID;
```

Now for the user billing phone you can use the WordPress function [`get_user_meta()][2]` this way:

```
// Get the user billing phone:
$user_phone = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', true );
```

Now you can use this code in your template:

```
<?php


if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email );

$user = get_user_by( 'login', $user_login ); // Get the user object (from the user login)
$user_id = $user->ID; // Get the user ID
$user_phone = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', true ); // User phone
?>

    <p><?php printf( __( 'Thanks for creating an account on %1$s. Your username is %2$s', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $blogname ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_login ) . '</strong>' ); ?></p>

<?php 
    // Display the user phone
    echo '<p>'.__( "Your registered user phone is: ", "woocommerce").$user_phone.'</p>';

if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) && $password_generated ) : ?>

    <p><?php printf( __( 'Your password has been automatically generated: %s', 'woocommerce' ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_pass ) . '</strong>' ); ?></p>
<p>Phone No:<?php echo get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_phone', true ) ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>

    <p><?php printf( __( 'You can access your account area to view your orders and change your password here: %s.', 'woocommerce' ), make_clickable( esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) ) ); ?></p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @LoicTheAztec  Your code working for me

Comment: Hi, Im trying to use same code to get custom user field in mail template but im getting blank value in mail. Can you help me

Comment: @NishaSharma To get the user ID in the email templates you will use the `$order` object variable that is mainly defined everywhere this way:
`$user_id = $order->get_customer_id();` or `$user_id = $order->get_user_id();`

Comment: i added this code but it disabled my checkout process. <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); 
$user_id = $order->get_user_id();
?> <?php echo $user_id; ?>

Comment: i also tried $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$user_id = $order->get_user_id(); but it returns 0 user id

Comment: @NishaSharma you should better ask a new question with your acyual code and details… then notify me. please

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I tried this code in email order template instead of new customer mail template and it  worked. Thanks